# How to properly extend an existing android module on github?

Tags: java, android

I want to extend a library from [github](https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java) I was wondering what is the proper way to import this into Android Studio.

I tried cloning the repo and created a new project in Android Studio. File > New > Import Module and then Open Module Settings. It noticed the module and so I imported it. Method I [followed](https://github.com/MagicMicky/FreemiumLibrary/wiki/Import-the-library-in-Android-Studio)

build.gradle added `implementation project(':socketcluster-client-java')`

I got a bunch of errors pretty much a multiple `Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :socketcluster-client-java.`